# What is the best design to this class?

Tags: c#, .net, static, class-design, instance

assume this class:

```
public class Logger
{
    static TextWriter fs = null;

    public Logger(string path)
    {
        fs = File.CreateText(path);
    }

    public static void Log(Exception ex)
    {
        ///do logging
    }

    public static void Log(string text)
    {
        ///do logging
    }
}
```

and I have to use this like:

```
Logger log = new Logger(path);
```

and then use `Logger.Log()` to log what I want. I just use one Logger.
the question is: is this a good design? to instantiate a class and then always call it's static method? any suggestion yield in better design is appreciated.

Edit based on [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)'s answer:

I flush on the last line of Log and there is no need for me to read the file while it is open, the issue with file not cleanly closed is right. this class simply satisfy my requirements and there is no need to be thread safe for it. I just want to get read of the instantiation part, I should get into the SetPath you said, any suggestion for closing file?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? : use log4Net instead

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish the use of a singular logger?

Comment: @HPT: Read up on the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, having a constructor just for this is bad design. A static `SetPath` method that can **only be called once** (else throws an exception) would seem better. You would set the path during app-startup, etc.

Then you can either make it a `static class`, or a singleton if it is required to satisfy some interface-based scenario.

Next: you **must** add synchronisation here! That is not thread safe. If two threads attempt to log at the same time, I would expect this to collapse horribly. It doesn't need to be complex; at the simplest:

```
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
public static void Log(string value) {
    lock(syncLock) {
        //...
    }
}
```

(but note that this may incur some blocking costs; which can be improved with more sophisticated code - see below)

There are existing logging libraries that will think of lots more issues - file partitioning, async (to stop your code being blocked by IO), batching, etc; why not just use one of them? In particular, at te moment your file will not be cleanly closed at app-exit, doesn't flush regularly, and will keep the file locked most of the time. Not good.

Comment: I'd love some expanding on the synchronisation part.

Comment: @Marc: I flush on the last line of `Log` and there is no need for me to read the file while it is open, the issue with file not cleanly closed is right. this class simply satisfy my requirements and there is no need to be thread safe for it. I just want to get read of the instantiation part, I should get into the `SetPath` you said, any suggestion for closing file?

Comment: What libraries do you recommend for logging other, there is a list in google but which one you prefer

Comment: @HPT - **every** static method **should** be thread safe. In particular, is this perhaps used in a web server scenario?

Comment: @Marc: no it just used in a winform single thread application.

Comment: @HPT re flush, fair enough; but note that in some cases even Flush doesn't **fully** flush - only Close does. But in this case you are right. For a counter-case, see GZipStream / DeflateStream.

Comment: @HPT if it is single thread, then the lock will never be contested. So I'd lock it **anyway**, and avoid the bugs when somebody adds a BackgroundWorker or ThreadPool use.

Comment: @Marc: I didnt get the issue with `GZipStream / DeflateStream`. How can I ensure that the my log file closesin my class?

Comment: @HPT well, you're not using gzip so it may not apply; but a Close() method seems pragmatic... If it was non-static I'd say IDisposable/Dispose()

Comment: @Marc: yes, I tried to use IDisposable but since it is static it is not possible. so is there a way to do this in current design?

Comment: @hpt - like I said; add a Close() method that you call before exiting

Answer (score 3):

No, this doesn't make sense. Each time a Logger is instantiated, the static TextWriter will be overwritten, which will affect all consumers of the class.  If you want to keep the instance constructor then you should make the TextWriter an instance field and the methods should be instance methods.

As an alternative, you may want to consider using log4net, which will do this kind of logging work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make whole class static with static property allowing you to set up the log path.

```
public static class Logger
{
    static TextWriter fs = null;

    public static string FileName
    {
      set
      {
        fs = File.CreateText(value);
      }
    }

    public static void Log(Exception ex)
    {
      if(fs == null) return;
        ///do logging
    }

    public static void Log(string text)
    {
      if(fs == null) return;
        ///do logging
    }
}
```